# pip install PATH set but not recognized by cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip

I have set the install path for pip with "setx PATH" and checked to make sure pip is installed there but it still does not recognize pip. I also tried setting the path with the environment variable path editor with the same path;

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages

but get the same result with pip not being recognized even though I can see pip installed there and Windows recognizes that.

> C:\Users[user]>py -m ensurepip --upgrade Looking in links:
> c:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5jiqkdus Requirement already
> up-to-date: setuptools in
> c:\users[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages

> (49.2.1) Requirement already up-to-date: pip in
> c:\users[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
> (20.2.1)

> C:\Users[user]>pip 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users[user]>setx PATH
> "%PATH%;C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages"
>
> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
>
> C:\Users[user]>pip 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file.

I can also see a pip installed in

> C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local

but since this was not what was recognized by "py -m ensurepip --upgrade" I figured that shouldn't be the path set. I tried setting the path for it regardless just to see and got the same result as the others.

> C:\Users[user]>setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local"
>
> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
>
> C:\Users[user]>pip 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file.

Why is windows not recognizing the pip path even though "py -m ensurepip --upgrade" does and I can see it installed there?

Comment: I _think_ you might need to use proper capitalzation `py -m PyInstaller` for this variant to work.

Comment: Capitalization with "py -m PyInstaller" worked even though for installation "py -m pip install pyinstaller" was fine. I guess it just doesnt apply for installing packages.

Answer (score 0):

A way around to solve this problem is to actually use Anaconda if it is possible. It also uses pip but it offers a multitude of encapsulated environments and a user friendly interface.